# Apache Mod Rewrite for CodeIgniter AND HTML5 mode

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have Codeigniter running on Apache and have Apache Mod Rewrite that works well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've now changed the front-end to be HTML5 and my app uses emulated URLs that suppose to be handled by the same 1-page application.
So I need something like the following URL rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

So, I'd like to combine those together.
First I'd like to see if the first part of URL path is a CI controller (a file in ./application/controllers) and if yes then rewrite it to index.php.
If not, I'd like to rewrite it to index.html.

I'm trying to build something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# -- RewriteCond ^/([^/]+)/ (application/controllers/$1.php) is a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

I understand that my other option it to manually specify all possible routes and controllers but would be nice to do it automatically...

---

UPDATE:

The proposed solution below helped me to solve the problem.
This is what worked for me eventually:

```
RewriteCond C:/projects/someproject/WS/application/controllers/$1.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond C:/projects/someproject/WS/application/controllers/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)/$
RewriteCond C:/projects/someproject/WS/application/controllers/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)/[^/]*/?$
RewriteCond C:/projects/someproject/WS/application/controllers/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# else, rewrite the request to /index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

I've realised I had to check for more types of URLs and also I found I couldn't use %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} because I'm using VirtualDocumentRoot settings and DOCUMENT_ROOT isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 # If /document_root/application/controllers/request.php is a file
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/controllers/$1.php -f
# Rewrite the request to /index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
# else, rewrite the request to /index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.html
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't exactly what I needed but it helped a lot. I'll update my original post to include what worked for me eventually.